# How to fix FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() in flutter app using firebase_auth package? It is always returning null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using the firebase_auth package to implement the authentication functionality in my flutter application and for auto-login of user I need a response from `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` which is always returning null. They have a Github issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17805) but it is closed and not have much details.

[Here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth#-changelog-tab-) is the link to package description. Do I need to migrate my project to AndroidX to make things work?
Is there any other way to make all of this work without migrating a project to AndroidX?

Answer (score 2):

after the update you can use it like this

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
```

instead of FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()

this will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use this

User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser ;